# Java 8 Time API - DB2/400 / JT400

Tags: jdbc, ibm-midrange, java-time, db2-400, jt400

I'm currently upgrading an application that uses DB2/400 database, and I'm migrating to the new java time api (LocalDate, LocalTime, ...), using the latest version of jt400.jar.

However, when executing statement setObject as follows

```
stmt.setObject(++columns, LocalDate.now());
```

I'm getting this exception

```
Thread[main,5,main]  Ter jan 18 10:46:56:852 GMT 2022  as400: PreparedStatementImpl STMT0001 (1588970020) : setObject().
Thread[main,5,main]  Ter jan 18 10:46:56:852 GMT 2022  as400: PreparedStatementImpl STMT0001 (1588970020) : parameter index: 2 type: java.time.LocalDate toString():2022-01-18.
Thread[main,5,main]  Ter jan 18 10:46:56:853 GMT 2022  as400: Unknown com.ibm.as400.access.SQLDate@3c679bde (1013423070) : Unable to assign object(2022-01-18) of class(class java.time.LocalDate).
Thread[main,5,main]  Ter jan 18 10:46:56:853 GMT 2022  as400: Unknown com.ibm.as400.access.SQLDate@3c679bde (1013423070) : Throwing exception, sqlState: 07006 reason: Data type mismatch. vendor code -99999.java.sql.SQLException: Data type mismatch.
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.createSQLExceptionSubClass(JDError.java:891)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:436)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.SQLDate.set(SQLDate.java:452)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCPreparedStatementImpl.setValue(AS400JDBCPreparedStatementImpl.java:3655)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCPreparedStatementImpl.setObject(AS400JDBCPreparedStatementImpl.java:3124)
    at mypackage.jdbc.LocalDateTester.main(LocalDateTester.java:26)
```

Also, when trying to read from the DB using

```
rs.getObject(2, LocalDate.class)
```

I'm also getting the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Data type not valid.
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.createSQLExceptionSubClass(JDError.java:985)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:436)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:413)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCResultSet.getObject(AS400JDBCResultSet.java:7457)
    at mypackage.jdbc.LocalDateTester.main(LocalDateTester.java:47)
```

The DB column type on iSeries is Date.

I'm I doing something wrong, or is the new java.time api not supported?

If so, does anyone know if there are any plans for Java Time API support?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You must use java.sql.date with JDBC.  Convert with :

`java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now());`